# How to properly use akka actors in scala

Tags: scala, akka, actor

I'm relatively new to the idea of actors, and was wondering if I could get some critique on what I am doing. For part of a project, I need to have an actor that tells a collection of listening actors the time. The listening actors must be able to be added to this actor.

Currently I have this:

```
import akka.actor.Actor;

import akka.actor.ActorRef;
import com.github.nscala_time.time.Imports._;

class TimeManager extends Actor {
  var actors:List[ActorRef] = List();
  def receive = {
    case AdvanceTime() => actors foreach (_ ! DateTime.now)
    case AddListener(x) => actors =  x :: actors
  }
}
```

Is there any way that I can remove the state (var actors) from this code to make it more functional?

Comment: It is best practice to have only one parent per child actor.  This means you should avoid passing Actors (and for that matter any mutable objects) as messages to other actors.  Try to structure the actor system as a heirarchy - this permits better supervision and control over the system.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't remove state since `TimeManager` should contain list of actors.

You could hide it:

```
class TimeManager extends Actor {
  def receive = getBehavior(Nil)
  def getBehavior(actors: List[ActorRef]): Receive = {
    case AdvanceTime() => actors foreach (_ ! DateTime.now)
    case AddListener(x) => context become getBehavior(x :: actors)
  }
}
```

Comment: Wow, interesting use of `become`!

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out. `getBehavior` has a return type of `Receive`. Therefore, it **can't take any arguments** when we call `context become getBehavior` because messages being sent to an actor are processed either with `receive` and some method which "become" -- methods that don't take any arguments. Correct? So what will supply the argument to `getBehavior`?

Comment: @Alex: `it can't take any arguments` - why? `Receive` is actually a `PartialFunction`, so `getBehavior` accepts `List` as parameter and creates a `PartialFunction`. And this `PartialFunction` is used by `Actor` to process messages. Method `receive` provides default behavior. After `become` method `receive` will not be used again.

Comment: I'm having difficulties to understand what become does. When I call "become(myFunc)", it means that **all** messages will go to `myFunc` since then, correct?

Comment: <<it can't take any arguments - why?>> -- because we can send only a message, we can't call "receive" directly supplying the arguments to it.

Comment: @Alex: Yes, it's correct. But there is a second argument in method `become`: `discardOld: Boolean = true`. You can specify it as `false` and use `unbecome`.

Comment: @Alex: type of `getBehavior _` is `List[ActorRef] => Receive`. So you can't pass to `become`. Type of `getBehavior(x :: actors)` is `Receive`.

Answer (score 1):

The strength of Scala is its hybrid of OO and Functional programming, scala developer don't need hate `var`, if you do, you may need choose Haskell.

In your case, I think the only thing you need to change is to make `actors` as `private`