# Initializing an actor before being able to handle some other messages

Tags: scala, asynchronous, akka, future

I have an actor which creates another one:

```
class MyActor1 extends Actor {
  val a2 = system actorOf Props(new MyActor(123))
}
```

The second actor must initialize (bootstrap) itself once it created and only after that it must be able to do other job.

```
class MyActor2(a: Int) extends Actor {
  //initialized (bootstrapped) itself, potentially a long operation 
  //how?
  val initValue = // get from a server

  //handle incoming messages
  def receive = {
    case "job1" => // do some job but after it's initialized (bootstrapped) itself
  }
}
```

So the very first thing `MyActor2` must do is do some job of initializing itself. It might take some time because it's request to a server. Only after it finishes successfully, it must become able to handle incoming messages through `receive`. Before that - it must not do that.

Of course, a request to a server must be asynchronous (preferably, using `Future`, not `async`, `await` or other high level stuff like `AsyncHttpClient`). I know how to use Future, it's not a problem, though.

How do I ensure that?

**p.s.** My guess is that it must send a message to itself first.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could use `become` method to change actor's behavior after initialization:

```
class MyActor2(a: Int) extends Actor {

  server ! GetInitializationData

  def initialize(d: InitializationData) = ???

  //handle incoming messages
  val initialized: Receive = {
    case "job1" => // do some job but after it's initialized (bootstrapped) itself
  }

  def receive = {
    case d @ InitializationData =>
      initialize(d)
      context become initialized
  }
}
```

Note that such actor will drop all messages before initialization. You'll have to preserve these messages manually, for instance using [`Stash`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/index.html#akka.actor.Stash):

```
class MyActor2(a: Int) extends Actor with Stash {

  ...

  def receive = {
    case d @ InitializationData =>
      initialize(d)
      unstashAll()
      context become initialized
    case _ => stash()
  }
}
```

If you don't want to use `var` for initialization you could create initialized behavior using `InitializationData` like this:

```
class MyActor2(a: Int) extends Actor {

  server ! GetInitializationData

  //handle incoming messages
  def initialized(intValue: Int, strValue: String): Receive = {
    case "job1" => // use `intValue` and `strValue` here
  }

  def receive = {
    case InitializationData(intValue, strValue) =>
      context become initialized(intValue, strValue)
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention I need to initialize `val initValue =` with the result of initialization. So, eventually `initValue` must hold the result of the initialization process.   What's the best way to do this?

Comment: @Alex: see update. You could change behavior without `var` many times - see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17208523/406435).

Comment: And if I want to use `var` then it would have the default (null) value initially and then would become defined?

Comment: shouldn't initialized return a Future? Otherwise it will block the thread.

Comment: @Alex: @`var`: yes, it will be `var intValue: Int = _`, but I prefer solution without `var`s. @`Future`: no, `def initialized` returns instantly, you don't need `Future` here (actually there is no way you could use it here).

Comment: I mean, if I send a request to a server from `MyActor2` (not using `server ! GetInitializationData` but `self ! InitItself; .... case InitItself => sendRequestToServer()`, shouldn't `sendRequestToServer()` return a Future?

Comment: @Alex: 1. why would you do this? 2. It depends on how `sendRequestToServer` works. To get response from server you should specify sender for method `!`. By default it will be you actor, so your actor will receive the response. But in case `sendRequestToServer` can't specify your actor as sender it should return `Future`. In this case you should use it like this: `sendRequestToServer().onSuccess{ resp => self ! InitializationData(resp) }`. You don't need `InitItself` message in this case.

Comment: 1) Due to curiosity.  2) Sorry, I didn't get it. Just tell me, is the new mavilein's solution the one you're talking about? Is his solution correct now?

Comment: @Alex: about new @mavilein's solution: `preStart` is called on every restart, there is no method `unstash` in `Stash` (use `unstashAll`), you have to add response to `InitializationDone` and parameters to `normalReceive`. [Like this](http://pastebin.com/8nV0BDAU).

Answer (score 5):

I don't know wether the proposed solution is a good idea. *It seems awkward to me to send a Initialization message.* Actors have a lifecycle and offer some hooks. When you have a look at the [API](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.2.3/#akka.actor.Actor), you will discover the `prestart` hook.

Therefore i propose the following:

- When the actor is created, its preStart hook is run, where you do your server request which returns a future.
- While the future is not completed all incoming messages are stashed.
- When the future completes it uses context.become to use your real/normal receive method.
- After the become you unstash everything.

Here is a rough sketch of the code (**bad solution, see real solution below**):

```
class MyActor2(a: Int) extends Actor with Stash{

  def preStart = {
    val future = // do your necessary server request (should return a future)
    future onSuccess {
      context.become(normalReceive)
      unstash()
    }
  }

  def receive = initialReceive

  def initialReceive = {
    case _ => stash()
  }

  def normalReceive = {
    // your normal Receive Logic
  }
}
```

**UPDATE:** Improved solution according to Senias feedback

```
class MyActor2(a: Int) extends Actor with Stash{

  def preStart = {
    val future = // do your necessary server request (should return a future)
    future onSuccess {
      self ! InitializationDone
    }
  }

  def receive = initialReceive

  def initialReceive = {
    case InitializationDone =>
      context.become(normalReceive)
      unstash()
    case _ => stash()
  }

  def normalReceive = {
    // your normal Receive Logic
  }

  case class InitializationDone
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but it's a bad solution. `onSuccess` will be executed in some thread that have nothing with your actor. You'll get a race condition on `stash()` and `unstash()`. Do not ever share actor's state! It breaks thread safety. The only valid way to change actor's state is message handling.

Comment: Oh yeah, you are right. Thx! I am still new to actors and forget some basic things sometimes :-). In the improved solution i am sending a message in onSuccess now, and doing the become and unstash in the receive.

Comment: Could you please explain why do you use `context.become(normalReceive)` and then `case _ => stash()`. Won't all message go to `normalReceive` after `become`? Will any of them reach `case _ => stash()`?

Comment: Ok. So the actor gets created. In runs preStart and does the server request. At this point the actor uses the initialReceive method, which means call messages will be stashed because they match the last clause. Then some time later the future gets completed and the InitializationDone message is sent. Then the actor switches to the normalReceive und does the unstash. Now all "saved" messages will be  processed by your normalReceive.

Comment: See [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591124/initializing-an-actor-before-being-able-to-handle-some-other-messages/20594295?noredirect=1#comment30815599_20591331). I guess after fix you'll get `sendRequestToServer().onSuccess{ resp => self ! InitializationData(resp) }` from [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20591124/initializing-an-actor-before-being-able-to-handle-some-other-messages/20594295?noredirect=1#comment30816602_20591331).

Comment: @senia, I can also use `preStart`, in this case I don't need to send itself a message "StartInit", correct?

Comment: @Alex: Note that `preStart` is [called](https://github.com/akka/akka/blob/master/akka-actor/src/main/scala/akka/actor/Actor.scala#L548) after every restart. I don't know if you need this. If you don't need to call it on every restart - just call `sendRequestToServer` in constructor.

Comment: @senia, well it depends. Do you think it's a good idea to call `sendRequestToServer` instead of sending itself the `StartInit` message  and handling it in `receive`? Note that `sendRequestToServer` may take a lot of time.

Comment: @Alex: if `sendRequestToServer` returns `Future` it should return it instantly. The only reason to use `Future` instead of `GetInitializationData` to server: you don't want server to know about initialization or you want to aggregate many responses from server. In other case `Future` is just an additional useless layer.

Comment: @Alex, @mavilein: using `preStart` could be a good idea if you want to re-initialize your actor on restart, but you have to add `context become initialReceive` into `preStart` to precess new response from server.

Comment: @senia: Thx for the insight that preStart is called on every restart. This is actually from different from what was explained in course on Reactive Programming Course on Coursera.

Comment: "During restarts preStart is called by the default implementation of postRestart, which means that by overriding that method you can choose whether the initialization code in this method is called only exactly once for this actor or for every restart."

Comment: @senia: I thought a little bit about it. And initializing your Actor is exactly what one wants, right? Because on every restart the state is lost and a new Actor object is created. You will have to initialize it again.